# What does the "Generate Validation Methods" checkbox in the Managed Object Class Generation dialog do?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, code-generation

What does the "Generate Validation Methods" checkbox in the Managed Object Class Generation dialog do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [Validation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003397-BBCEHEGG) in the Core Data Programming Guide.